# filter array of object base on array of object

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6

This is my data

```
[{name:'james',grade:'A'},
{name:'john',grade:'B'},
{name:'iris',,grade:'A'},
{name:'ivan',,grade:'C'}]
```

I want to keep object that has grade A and C, it's easy I can just do filter like

`person.filter(obj => obj.grade === 'A' || obj.grade === 'C')`

but now I have an array of object.

`[{grade:'A'},{grade:'C'}]`

any clue how can I do filtering now? do I need nested loop?

Comment: You mean you have an array of arrays?

Comment: @AndrewLi no, array of object

Comment: Can you give an example of the data you're dealing with? Your question is unclear

Comment: @AndrewLi 'C' and 'A' is not string or value stored in any variable but array of object.

Comment: What's wrong with your current code? The way you've phrased your question implies it should work. It's confusing.

Comment: Trying out your code, it gives me `[
  {"name":"james","grade": "A"},{"name": "iris","grade":"A"},{"name":"ivan","grade": "C"}]`, not `[{grade:'A'},{grade:'C'}]`. Your filter is correct

Comment: No one understands "*how can I do filtering now*". What filtering do you want to do "now"? The result of your first filter should be `[{name:'james',grade:'A'},{name:'iris',grade:'A'},{name:'ivan',grade:'C'}]`. PS, you can't have elisions in objects, only arrays.

Comment: Oh, so you want to filter the `data` based on the `array of object` ... why didn't you say so

Comment: @JaromandaX—thanks, finally got it. I think.

Comment: @Giala Yes, the question is very misleading. Many of us thought that your filter didn't work, when actually it worked and you want to apply a second filter based on a predicate. I think "But now I have an array of object" has been understood as "But the result of my filter is an array of object and I don't want that"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`Array.prototype.some`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some):

```js
let person = [{name:'james', grade:'A'},
              {name:'john', grade:'B'},
              {name:'iris', grade:'A'},
              {name:'ivan', grade:'C'}];

let predicate = [{grade:'A'},{grade:'C'}];
        
let result = person.filter(obj => predicate.some(p => p.grade == obj.grade))

console.log('result:', result)
```

If your predicate is more dynamic than that, compare all object properties instead of just `p.grade`.

```
person.filter(obj => predicate.some(p => {
    return Object.keys(p).every(k => obj[k] == p[k]);
}));
```

Comment: Your predicate is wrong, it doesn't include names. OP's output is weird, because it discards names for some reason, keeping only the grades.

Comment: No, `predicate` is OP's *"but now I have an array of object"*. `person` is the first array which includes names. Edited to clarify.

Comment: Oh damn, I think I just understood the question. I thought his filter was wrong, but actually he wants to reapply a second filter. Sorry

Comment: I can see where you fell off the wagon there… :)

Comment: some is enough to do the job although I don't understand the second block of ur code.

Comment: @Giala The second block compares every property and its value in `predicate` to the same property value of the person. So, your `predicate` could be `{grade: 'A', name: 'james'}`, for instance.

Answer (score 0):

Using underscore lib 
eg -

```
    var bbb = [
        {id: 839},
        {id: 854}
    ];
     var ids = {};
    _.each(bbb, function (bb) { ids[bb.id] = true; });

var data = [{grade:'A'},{grade:'C'}];
var value = {};
_.each(data , function (d) { value[data.garde] === 'A' | value[data.garde] === 'C' ; });
```

Comment: Code-only answers aren't helpful. What is the OP's issue? How does your code fix it?

Comment: @JeremyThille i guess using libraries is makes the code cleaner i feel it purely optionaly i feel

Comment: Yes sorry, I misunderstood OP's question. I de-downvoted your answer :)

Answer (score 0):

Objects having grades `A` and `C` should be filtered as (classic js syntax),

```
var a = [
  {name:'james',grade:'A'},
  {name:'john',grade:'B'},
  {name:'iris',grade:'A'},
  {name:'ivan',grade:'C'}
];

a.filter(function(e) { 
  return (e.grade == 'A') || (e.grade == 'C');
});
```

Comment: what's wrong with that answer? -)) missing semicolon? -))

Comment: I made the same mistake, I misunderstood OP's question. His first filter works, but now he wants to apply a second filter based on predicate `[{grade:'A'},{grade:'C'}]`. His question is very misleading indeed. (I didn't downvote)

Comment: i dont really care about downvotes but I really didn't understand what he wants -))

Comment: Well you don't come and help people on Stackoverflow to get downvoted, do you? :)

Comment: sure, but "sapere aude"  outweighs such situations -))

Comment: what is this even means?

Answer (score 0):

If you have many grades to check (I don't know like all of them ;) ). You could first convert array into `Set`

```
const grades = new Set([{grade:'A'},{grade:'C'}].map(({grade}) => grade))

const persons = [{name:'james',grade:'A'},
  {name:'john',grade:'B'},
  {name:'iris',grade:'A'},
  {name:'ivan',grade:'C'}]
```

And then filter persons array using [`has`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set/has)

```
const filtered = persons.filter(({grade}) => grades.has(grade))
```

Comment: surely this can be more generic, so that if user wants to also add a filter item `{name:'john'}` you wouldn't have to rewrite it :p (good answer though)

Answer (score 0):

You could use a [`Set`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set) for the predicates and filter accordingly

```js
let person = [{ name: 'james', grade: 'A' }, { name: 'john', grade: 'B' }, { name: 'iris', grade: 'A' }, { name: 'ivan', grade: 'C' }],
    predicate = [{ grade: 'A' }, { grade: 'C' }],
    result = person.filter((s => p => s.has(p.grade))(new Set(predicate.map(p => p.grade))));

console.log(result)
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```